# Calling subprocess.Popen with stdin, stdout, and stderr set to subprocess.PIPE changes the behavior of the terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I recently developed a Python script to leverage a tool to retrieve metrics from JVMs via JMX. The parent process (`p1`) uses the following code to start another process (`p2`).

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(
    ['java', '-jar', '/path/to/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar',
     '-l', url, '-u', username, '-p', password],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Once `p2` is up and running, `p1` enters a very long loop in which it does the following three things:

1. sleeps for 10 seconds;
2. sends a query to `p2` by calling `p2.stdin.write()`;
3. reads the result by calling `p2.stdout.readline()`.

Questions:

1. My script works as expected until it quits. If I stop `p1` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and return to the terminal, everything works just fine. If I wait until `p1` finishes the long loop and quits, the terminal works all right except that all the characters I type in can no longer be seen. For example, if I type in 'ls', I see nothing on the screen. But when I hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, I can still see the files and subdirectories listed as usual. My question is, what happens behind the curtain?
2. If I remove `stderr = subprocess.PIPE`, the help messages printed to `stderr` by jmxterm goes to the terminal. Because they mess up with the output of my script, I tried to change

   ```
   ['java', '-jar', '/path/to/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar', '-l', url,
            '-u', username, '-p', password]
   ```

   to

   ```
   ['java', '-jar', '/path/to/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar', '-l', url,
            '-u', username, '-p', password, '2>/dev/null']
   ```

   But nothing changed (the help messages still went to the terminal). I then added `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` back to my script and start a daemon thread to read from `stderr` and discard whatever it reads. To my surprise, the daemon thread read nothing from `stderr`. I am TOTALLY lost. Please give me a hand if you have a clue.

For your reference, the code is pasted below:

```
from Queue import Queue

class JmxD(Detector):

    def __init__(self, myId, jmxUrl, username, password):
        super(JmxD, self).__init__(myId)

        self.__jmxUrl = jmxUrl
        self.__username = username
        self.__password = password

        # Start JMX terminal
        self.__jmxTerm = subprocess.Popen(
            ['java', '-jar', jmxTermPath,
             '-l', jmxUrl, '-u', username, '-p', password],
            stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

        # Start two daemon threads to read from JMX terminal's stdout & stderr
        def _stream2Queue(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, ''):
                line = line.strip()
                if line:
                    queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        def _stream2Null(out):
            for line in iter(out.readline, ''):
                #print 'A line read from stderr: %s' % line.strip()
                pass
            out.close()

        self.__queue = Queue()
        self.__reader = Thread(target=_stream2Queue,
                               args=(self.__jmxTerm.stdout, self.__queue))
        self.__reader.setDaemon(True) # This thread dies with the program
        self.__reader.start()

        self.__discarder = Thread(target=_stream2Null,
                                  args=(self.__jmxTerm.stderr))
        self.__discarder.setDaemon(True) # This thread dies with the program
        self.__discarder.start()
```

Comment: my guess is the java process is messing with the terminal when it closes properly. If you just want to get your terminal back to normal, then just run `reset` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Pykler: Thanks for the trick.

Comment: don't use `stderr=PIPE` unless you are reading it. Call `p2.communicate()` after the loop to close the streams and wait for `p2` to exit.

Comment: J.F. Sebastian: Many thanks for your reply. I just encountered another issue. Would you please take a look and let me know if you have a clue? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, here's why adding `2>/dev/null` didn't work: When you type `2>/dev/null` at the end of a command in your terminal, the shell catches it and interprets it as a command to set up the "machinery" to discard anything the process prints to standard error. After stripping out special shell instructions like that, the shell takes what's left over and passes it as a list of arguments to the C version of `Popen`. When using Python's `Popen`, you don't have a shell to interpret those special shell instructions, so they don't do anything. (FYI there is a `shell=True` option to `Popen.)